# xml with xsl:sort not sorting

Tags: java, xml, sorting, xslt

I have an xml document that I need to sort by date. I have a java program that calls an xsl stylesheet template. The output is just the same xml but should be sorted by date descending. The sort is not working. The result I get is the output looks the same as the input.

Here is what the source xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ABCResponse xmlns="http://www.example.com/Schema">
    <ABCDocumentList>
        <ABCDocument>
            <DocumentType>APPLICATION</DocumentType>
            <EffectiveDate>20140110010000</EffectiveDate>
            <Name>JOE DOCS</Name>
        </ABCDocument>
        <ABCDocument>
            <DocumentType>FORM</DocumentType>
            <EffectiveDate>20140206010000</EffectiveDate>
            <Name>JOE DOCS</Name>
        </ABCDocument>
        <ABCDocument>
            <DocumentType>PDF</DocumentType>
            <EffectiveDate>20140120010000</EffectiveDate>
            <Name>JOE DOCS</Name>
        </ABCDocument>
    </ABCDocumentList>
</ABCResponse>
```

Java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;



public class TestMisc {


       /**
       * @param args
       */
       public static void main(String[] args) {
              Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new File("c:/temp/ABCListDocsResponse.xml"));
              Source xsl = new StreamSource(new File("c:/temp/DocResponseDateSort.xsl"));
              Result xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new File("c:/temp/ABC_output1.xml"));

              try {
                     javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory transFact =
                     javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(  );

                     javax.xml.transform.Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsl);

                     trans.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);

              } catch (TransformerException e) {

            }

          }

      }
```

Here is the XSL

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ABCResponse/ABCDocumentList/ABCDocument">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="EffectiveDate"  data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort the ABCDocuments, you need to stop one level higher. You also need to use namespaces correctly since your source XML uses namespaces:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ex="http://www.example.com/Schema">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ex:ABCDocumentList">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ex:ABCDocument">
        <xsl:sort select="ex:EffectiveDate" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I changed my stylesheet to stop one level higher like suggested but the output xml still wasn't sorted.

Comment: The XSLT also needs to use namespaces correctly. Answer updated.